# JavaScript search with regex, why is the plus operator causing problems?

Tags: javascript, regex, search, keyword

I'm writing a search tool program in javascript that has a simple keyword search. This piece of code basically checks to see that the keyword field isn't empty, then it uses a regex to check for any matches against an array. If there are matches, it sets a variable to be true and later uses to check again before pushing onto another array.

So the keyword search works for most of my keywords except where I have a plus sign involved. One of the keywords is `3+2`, it matches when I test it with `3+` or `2` or `3`, but it doesn't match when I test it with `+` or `+2` or `3+2`.

On top of that, if I start it with a `+` or `+2`, it doesn't execute this piece of code. It's like there's nothing that was entered.

I would appreciate any insight.

```
if (this.keywords_val !== ''){
    var regex = new RegExp(this.keywords_val, "gi");
    if (degrees[i].keywords.replace(/ /g, '').match(regex)) check_keyword = true;
    else check_keyword = false;
}
if ((check === true) && (check_keyword === true)) matches.push(degrees[i]);
else nonmatches.push(degrees[i].name.replace(/ /g, ''));
```

Comment: What expression do you need to test ? + sign should be escaped if you need to include it in the search (like \+).

Comment: Try `\+?\d?\+?\d?` [here](https://regex101.com/r/82AkMM/1)